# Would making package in Java something other that a folder be a good idea?

Tags: java, language-features

Right now, that is all a package is. So when I create a new Package in Eclipse, I am just asked its name. But what if Package was something like or exactly like Interface and everything under the Package would have to implement that interface? Or at least Package is a place to store descriptive info?

Dumb idea or not?

EDIT: I just noticed that Eclipse creates automatically the file package-info.java -- this serves the purpose I was aiming at in this question.

Comment: Why would you want that

Comment: Package names usually are indicative of the type or category of classes/objects that are contained within that package. Categorizing content into descriptive packages enhances readability of code and should be encouraged.

Comment: <Jan> One reason is that I see an interface that all classes implement being a different thing than the classes themselves might not belong in the same place as those classes. I am sort of proposing that package might serve as an interface. But if not that, it would be simply the place where you would document the package (the name of the package is obviously not enough to fully convey this sort of info). So that in an IDE like eclipse, you could click on the package and get this info. This would not be a change in Java but in Eclipse. You create a new package and it asks for a description.

Comment: You *can* put a package description in the Javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

Packages are usually used for structuring your files (classes, interfaces, e.t.c,).
Only addition is that your default access specifier in Java is Package private.
i.e., classes/interfaces for which you do not explicitly specify the access modifier, it remains accessible throughout that package.

Answer (score 0):

package-info.java does what I was looking for.